# Create attribute field on a geopackage with precision using QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, geopackage, display, precision

[image]
On a QGIS geopckage when I create a new field for decimal numbers, I can only create it as a decimal (real). So it populates the field with many decimals as shown. I don't mind having more decimal places for the fields. But when I make a map with attributes on print composer, I would like to show only three decimal values.

I don't want to use refactor fields or other processing tools at later stage because I import a lot files so that I can avoid extra steps to link it to the map.

Comment: You want a new field, but not use tools? Please elaborate. Also make clear, whether you care about the number of decimals in the attributes, or not.

Comment: I don't care about number of decimal places on the field. When I create a map with attribute on print composer, I just want to limit the number of decimal places to two or three.

Comment: So your question is "how do I shorten the label to these columns"?